# Alt Select - Office 2007 - Not working

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

For some weird reason, rectangular selection using alt+left button select doesn't work.

The actual box can be drawn and I can even make the text bold using the buttons on the ribbon panel.
But when I try to right click the rectangular selection to bring up the context menu, the selection is reduced to a SINGLE line. I'm not sure why this happens.

To illustrate the problem better, I recorded a video on youtube.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_OK7WEcwx4&feature=youtu.be

Tried this on different computers, same problem. A friend mentioned that his computer doesn't have this problem but I can't verify why.

**Can somebody check this for me on his machine?**

Btw, in office 2013, rectangular selection right click context menu works fine.
Is it a bug in earlier versions of office?

Comment: Just checked, and right-clicking the Alt+mouse selected block brings up the context menu just fine without modifying the selection, in Word 2010 and 2013 at least. Cannot confirm on 2007 right now though. Perhaps you can try repairing Office.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this is a bug in 2007 as well. Any idea on how to go about reporting it? What are the chances of it being fixed? I dread buying 2013 just for this purpose. :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's because you're right-clicking the block to bring up the quick menu.

If you select the block and then click the Bold in the ribbon (or use the keyboard short-cut, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) it works.

Also if you keep the mouse around where you ended the selection block (maybe move it around a bit) the quick menu will show on it's own without right-clicking, and when it does actions used on it affect the whole selected block.  The auto-showing does seem a little buggy.

Comment: yes, using the hover technique, it is possible to apply bold formatting. However, I wish to go to the the context menu to change advanced paragraph/line settings. 
(I think I should change the question to make this clearer)
This is not possible simply from the hover menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check Word 2007 and right-clicking an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+mouse selected block does *not* modify the selection in any way. Since your friend too doesn't have this problem, looks like your copy is corrupted. Try repairing Office, or uninstall and reinstall and hopefully that'll fix it.

Comment: hmm.. this is weird. I tried on 2 computers and can confirm the bug is there. Can u post a video showing that it works?

Comment: I'll see if I can record a video, but didn't you yourself state that a friend of yours doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Sry for the confusion. I'm not sure what office version he is on. Hence, the "friend info" is useless actually. The tests done by you guys are much more reliable.
Anyway I'm putting the problem on hold atm, since it isn't urgent. Thanks a lot for ur replies!